# Definition of topological group via neighborhood base -- weird difference condition

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

It's been over 2 years since I've seriously done point-set topology, so my apologies if this is simple. I'm working out of Liu's *Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves*. My question concerns a definition on page 16.

Liu defines a topological group in the standard way. Let us only consider abelian groups, and define a topological group to be a group with a topological structure so that $(x,y)\rightarrow x-y$ form $G\times G$ to $G$ is continuous.

It is not hard to see that if $U$ is an open set and $x$ is an element, then $U\rightarrow x+U$ is a homeomorphism, so we can specify the topological on a topological group $G$ by giving a neighborhood base at $0$.

Let $S$ be such a neighborhood base at $0$ of some group $G$, and let $V$ be any element in $S$. Liu claims there must exist elements $V_1,V_2\in S$, so that $V$ contains $V_1-V_2$ so that subtraction is continuous, and that the existence of such elements will make subtraction continuous. If we consider the inverse of $V$, then we would have $V_1\times V_2 \subset f^{-1}(V)$, where $f$ is subtraction. But this only gives an open neighborhood of $0$ in the inverse, and we need an open neighborhood of every point. Certainly the existence of $V_1$ and $V_2$ is necessary for subtraction to be continuous in this topology, but why is it sufficient?

Here's an attempt, using the fact that the topology is homogeneous. Let $U$ be any open set. Letting $f$ be subtraction, we must show $f^{-1}(U)$ is open. That is, given any $(a,b)\in f^{-1}(U)$, we must show an open neighborhood of $(a,b)$ is contained in $f^{-1}(U)$. Suppose $f(a,b)=c\in U$. Consider $c^{-1}U$, a neighborhood of $0$. By hypothesis, there exist $V_1,V_2$, both neighborhoods of $0$, so that $f(V_1\times V_2)\subset c^{-1}U$. Then $(V_1+a,V_2+b)$ gives the desired neighborhood of $(a,b)$ in $f^{-1}(U)$, since $f((V_1+a,V_2+b))\subset U$.

Comment: You have $V_1,V_2\in S$ with $V_1\times V_2\subseteq f^{-1}[V]$ and hence $V_1-V_2\subseteq V$; isn’t that exactly what you want?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I don't see why that implies the inverse image of $V$ is open. I only see why it implies the inverse image contains an open neighborhood around zero, but not why it contains an open neighborhood around every point.

Comment: Now I don’t understand what you’re asking. I thought that you were trying to prove the claim that such $V_1$ and $V_2$ exist. Are you actually saying that Liu imposes this condition on $S$ (and what others?) and asking why it makes subtraction continuous?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott My apologies. I did not write the question well. Yes, that is what I'm saying. This is the only claim he imposes.

Comment: Okay, now it makes sense. Just to be safe, what other conditions does he impose on $S$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott No others. "Such a structure is entirely determined by giving a fundamental system S of neighborhoods of 0 such that every element V of S contains the difference $V_1-V_2$ of two elements of S." (That ends the paragraph, and the preceding sentence defines a topological group.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm confused by your "presumably ..." Use continuity of subtraction, taking the preimage $U$ of $V$, noting that $(0,0)\in U$, and so we get $V_1\times V_2\subset U$. OK, you edited, so now I have to inquire: $S$ is the basis at $0$, so what are you worrying about?

OK, given the latest version, given $(a,b)\in G\times G$, let $V+(a-b)$ be a nbhd of $a-b$ and check that subtraction maps $(a+V_1)\times (b+V_2)$ into it.